# Adding a classic ASP webapplication to VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp-classic, solution

is there a way to add an existing classic ASP webapp into a solution in VS? The application is around 4000 files large and currently maintained outisde Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with Visual Studio 2008 out of the box, but you can if you install Service Pack 1 - see S[cott Guthrie's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx) for more info.

**Edit:** To clarify, whilst you can create a project out of the box, there is no intellisense or debugging unless you install SP1

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this IMO is:-

In VS 2008 File | Open | Web Site...

In the dialog ensure File System is selected.  Navigate to the physical folder that represents the root of your Web app.

Click Open.  Job Done.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real point though is there? As Classic ASP files aren't compiled. I keep just opening them individually as needed from File Explorer.

Although you could add them all to a VBProj or CSProj so you get them all showing up in your Solution Explorer, and could use features like Project -> Deploy.